# Component square integration on the unit $n$-sphere

Tags: integration, manifolds, surface-integrals, spheres

I found (with some hints from a nice math.se user) numerically that 
$$\int_{S^{n}} x^2 dS = \frac{1}{n+1} \int_{S^{n}} dS$$
where $S^n$ is [the unit $n$-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $x$ of course the first dimension. Now one could use the unit $n$-sphere surface area formula for the RHS and try to solve the LHS integral in order to prove this, but I am only mildly interested in such an approach.

My actual questions are:

1. Is there some fancy trick that elegantly proves the conjecture without heavy integration, gamma functions, et cetera?
2. Can you provide some intuition on this remarkable factor $n+1$ holding in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ ?

An exemplary consequence of the conjecture (and my gateway to this topic) is the covariance matrix
$$\text{E}(\mathbf{uu}^\text{T}) = \frac{1}{n} \, \mathbf{I}_n$$
of [uniformly random unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Uniformly_at_random_from_the_.28n.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A01.29-sphere) $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By symmetry, $\int_{S^n}f(x_i)dS = \int_{S^n}f(x_j)dS$ for all $i,j$. Hence
$$\begin{align}(n+1)\int_{S^n} x_0^2\ dS &= \int_{S^n}x_0^2\ dS + \int_{S^n}x_1^2\ dS + \ldots +\int_{S^n}x_n^2\ dS\\&=\int_{S^n}x_0^2 + x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2\ dS\\&=\int_{S^n} 1\ dS\end{align}$$

Comment: I am loving it. Thank you!